# Php Zend Framework : Connecting to multiple databases one at a time

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have written a script that goes through my application ini.

The problem I am having now is that when I get to the next database, its still selecting from the first database and not the new one.

Is it possible to close a connection and then open a new connection while running a script. Remember this is just  a script I have no bootstrap set. I just setup a autoload to that I can load my models.

While looping through sections of the ini

```
try {
        $db = Zend_Db::factory($section->database->type, $section->database->toArray());
        Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
        Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);
    } catch(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {
        continue;   
    }
```

Comment: if you set Zend_Registry::set('db', $db); at every loop, you have only the last one in the registry

Answer (score 6):

See [Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb):

**application.ini**

```
[production]
resources.multidb.db1.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.multidb.db1.host = "localhost"
resources.multidb.db1.username = "webuser"
resources.multidb.db1.password = "XXXX"
resources.multidb.db1.dbname = "db1"

resources.multidb.db2.adapter = "pdo_pgsql"
resources.multidb.db2.host = "example.com"
resources.multidb.db2.username = "dba"
resources.multidb.db2.password = "notthatpublic"
resources.multidb.db2.dbname = "db2"
resources.multidb.db2.default = true
```

**index.php**

```
$resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('multidb');
$db1 = $resource->getDb('db1');
$db2 = $resource->getDb('db2');
$defaultDb = $resource->getDb();
```

Comment: some times you have to use like this : `$resource['multidb']->getDb('db1');`

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who hasn't got a solution, all you have to do is this:

1. **application.ini** -> Define your databases here

   resources.multidb.**db**.adapter = SQLSRV

   resources.multidb.db.host = localhost

   resources.multidb.db.username = root

   resources.multidb.db.password =

   resources.multidb.db.dbname =

   resources.multidb.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

   resources.multidb.**db2**.adapter = SQLSRV

   resources.multidb.db2.host = localhost

   resources.multidb.db2.username = root

   resources.multidb.db2.password =

   resources.multidb.db2.dbname =

   resources.multidb.db2.isDefaultTableAdapter = false
2. **controller or model where connection to 2nd DB needs to be set up**

   $db2Ob = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('multidb')->getDb('**db2**');
3. Now use this $db2Ob to execute queries:

   $select = $db2Ob->select()->from(array('db2tbl' => 'table in 2nd DB'),array('column name'))->where(condition);

Hope this helps someone.

Regards,

Supriya Rajgopal