# Change database name in Model Zend Db Table

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to Zend Framework. I have declared database name and user name/password in application.ini like this:

```
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "root"
resources.db.params.dbname = "abc"
```

Now when I make a model class ,then I have to just declare table name like

```
protected $_name = "table1"
```

then it just to connect to "table1" in db "abc". Now I want to change dbname to "xyz" and connect to table "table2". Can I do it without changing the default database in application.ini somewhere in model class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check these [<strike>link1</strike>](http://www.amazium.com/blog/using-different-databases-with-zend-framework), [link2](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2011/05/connect-to-multiple-databases-with-zend-framework/)

and also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630370/php-zend-framework-connecting-to-multiple-databases-one-at-a-time)

Comment: First link appears to be dead.. fyi

Answer (score 0):

Use this code within model class.

```
public function __construct($config = array()) {
    $config['schema'] = "db_name";
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```